# UseMySQL extension method not recognized in ASP.NET core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04, .NET Core 1.10 (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177), Visual Studio Code 1.8.1

I have created an ASP.NET MVC Core application by running the following command:

```
$ dotnet new -t web
```

I am able to load the folder in VSC and debug it.

By default, the engine generates code for Sqlite. I am changing it to use MySQL. My changes are based on the information from the following two articles:

http://insidemysql.com/howto-starting-with-mysql-ef-core-provider-and-connectornet-7-0-4/
https://damienbod.com/2016/08/26/asp-net-core-1-0-with-mysql-and-entity-framework-core/

First, I added the following lines into `dependencies` section of `project.json`.

```
"MySql.Data.Core" :"7.0.4-ir-191",
"MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.6-IR31"
```

After running `dotnet restore`, the required DLLs were downloaded.

The next step was to modify Startup.cs and modify

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

to

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Essentially, I am replacing `UseSqlite` by `UseMySQL`.

However, extension method `UseMySQL` or `UseMySQL` do not seem to be available on `DbContextOptionsBuilder`.

Wondering if I missed some step somewhere. Regards.

Comment: Missing `using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;` declaration? Or you're using the wrong version. `7.0.6-IR31` is for EF Core 1.0. The latest one for EF Core 1.1 is `6.10.0-alpha`

Comment: I'm having the same problem but for Oracle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390383/in-dotnetcore-startup-cs-configureservices-dbcontext-options-is-missing-useor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the [`using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/) statement.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: where you find it ?

Answer (score 4):

I've successfully used this in my Mac with the latest version of VS Community in to an ASP CORE MVC project and I just needed to add the following NuGet-Packages:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore  
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore
```

Then using them on your class like:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
```

Notice the MySQL on the USING statement is CAPITAL letter, and it is MySql on the NuGet Package name.
Hope this hel

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue even though was installing the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql,
just installed the package through the terminal:

`dotnet add package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`

it worked!