# In dotnetcore, startup.cs, ConfigureServices, DbContext options is missing UseOracle()

Tags: .net-core, oracle-manageddataaccess

Where is the option for "UseOracle" ?
services.AddDbContext(options => options.useoracle()

I believe I've included the required DLL's.

Screenshot provided: 
https://pasteboard.co/HuVDEfB.png

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Because this person: https://dzone.com/articles/entity-framework-core-1-entity-framework-7-support
and this person: http://qaru.site/questions/2416423/using-identityserver4-with-custom-configration-dbcontext

Were both able to use "optionsBuilder.UseOracle" and I know I can too. I just don't know which DLL I need to include, that's my guess at what I'm doing wrong, I just haven't figured it out yet unfortunately.  I'll update this when or if I figure it out.

Comment: This method should reside either in one of the Microsoft DLL's or Oracle's DLL's.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore;
```